# Why i cant hover on bootstrap element?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm trying to hover an element in bootstrap. I use `!important` but it's not working.

**Html**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" role="tablist">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>        
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**Css**

```
ul>li>a {
    color: black;
    padding: 15px;
}

ul>li>a:hover {
    background-color: #B0B0B0;
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Code is correct. But need more information to figure out what is going on here. Do you use framework?

Comment: Im only use bootstrap library

Comment: It's unclear wherever it is not hoverable (how you cannot hover) or it doesn't change the style on hover. Making a a runnable code snippet included in the post could be better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to overwrite bootstrap css by add your css with full path of css selector like this.

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a{
  color: black !important;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a:hover{
    background-color: #b0b0b0;
    color: red;
}
```

```css
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link{
  color: black !important;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover{
    background-color: #b0b0b0;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```